# How can I wait a promise to be resolved before rendering a component with react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React Router, and their example for Private Routes is:

```
const fakeAuth = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = true
    setTimeout(cb, 100) // fake async
  },
  signout(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = false
    setTimeout(cb, 100)
  }
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)
```

My question is: How can I call an endpoint before rendering the component, in order to validate if the token stored in the session storage is still valid? So, my `PrivateRoute` will `redirect` only if I don't have anything on my session storage (I can do this easily), or if the access token in session storage is not valid any more (here is where I'm calling my API to see if it's still valid.

Answer (score -1):

Why not using this.setState? Its second argument allows you to have a callback. You could redirect the user within it